# How to solve recursion with two separate converges rates

Tags: asymptotics, recursion, big-o-notation

What is the correct way to solve the following recursion:
$T(n)=T(\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil) + T(n-2)$

Or basically any recursion that has two parts which converge in a different rate.

I'm trying to get big $O$ approximation, as tight as possible, but I couldn't figure it out with any "traditional" approach.

Comment: Try using the [Akra-Bazzi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method).

Comment: @Steven It won't work, however, since $n-2$ is not of the form $(b \pm o(1)) n$ for $b < 1$.

Comment: I seem to recall that a similar recurrence was discussed some time back.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus. Following Wikipedia's definition, writing $T(n-2)$ as $a T(bn +h(n))$ with $a=b=1$ and $h(n)=-2$ seems to be a valid choice.

Comment: @Steven. According to the wiki link you added, $b$ needs to be smaller then 1, so I guess this is not a valid choice, no?

Comment: @OfirGordon, ooooh. Yes, you are perfectly right. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take the initial conditions $T(0) = 0$ and $T(1) = 1$ then you get [A018819](http://oeis.org/A018819) (up to shift), which is essentially [A000123](http://oeis.org/A000123). The asymptotics are known to be $T(n) = n^{\Theta(\log n)}$. The references under the second entry contain more accurate asymptotic information.

More explicitly, A018819 satisfies the recurrence $a(2m+1) = a(2m) = a(2m-1) + a(m)$, with $a(0) = a(1) = 1$. You can show inductively that $a(n) = T(n+1)$. Indeed:

- If $n = 2m+1$ then $$T(n+1) = T(2m+2) = T(m+1) + T(2m) = a(m) + a(2m-1) = a(2m) = a(2m+1) = a(n).$$
- If $n = 2m$ then $$T(n+1) = T(2m+1) = T(m+1) + T(2m-1) = a(m) + a(2m-2) = a(m) + a(2m-1) = a(2m) = a(n).$$

Comment: Seems interesting, but can you please explain how the problems are equivalent? (Why is the recursion sollution is asymptotically equals to number of partitions of 2n into powers of 2, according to the second link you added)? Thanks.

Comment: The first entry contains a recurrence relation for A018819. You can prove inductively that the solutions of this recurrence (possibly shifted) are the same as the solution of your recurrence with my initial conditions.

Comment: Thaks a lot. I have a followup question though - if we replace the constant in the denominator, say $T(\lceil\frac{n}{4}\rceil)$ (or other constant, 4 is just an example), how would it effect the asimptotic bound? or is this a totally different equation that needs to be solved in a different way?

Comment: I imagine the solution would still be $n^{\Theta(\log n)}$.